# Hermite interpolation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, interpolation, hermite-polynomials

this is my first question here and I hope to find the answer because I already tried to find it in some books and videos (even in french) but I didn't find the answer.

**My question is:** *Where did Hermite interpolation come from?*

I know the formula:

$$P_{2n+1}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{f(x_{i})\left[1-2(x-x_{i})L'_{i}(x)\right]L^2_{i}(x)}+\sum_{i=0}^{n}{f'(x_{i})(x-x_{i})L^2_{i}(x)}$$

But how did they find it?

Someone told me it was linear algebra that helps to find the formula but I don't understand how.

N.B. :Sorry for any language faults, I don't speak English.

Comment: Define "come from". I mean, it came from Charles Hermite, and from France, but I feel like that's not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I mean how did Charles Hermite find it?